# concatenate date column and time column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to combine the data from a date column and a time column. I'm using the following code:

```
Sub Concat()

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lRow
     Cells(i, 10) = Cells(i, 6) & " " & Cells(i, 7)
     Cells(i, 11) = Cells(i, 8) & " " & Cells(i, 9)
Next I

Cells(1, 9).Copy
Cells(1, 10).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Cells(1, 11).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Cells(1, 10) = "Request Time"
Cells(1, 11) = "Validation Time"

End Sub
```

the result I get is this:

```
 Input data:
 Creation_Date  Creation Time     Change Date     Change Time   Request Time                    Validation Time
 01/23/2017     8:20:10           01/23/2017      8:20:10       1/23/2017 0.347337962962963     1/23/2017 0.347337962962963
```

The time turns into a decimal that cannot be converted back to a time. before concatenate function, the date column is formatted for date and the time column is formatted to time.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying data type of a date/time format is most likely a 64-bit floating. I would suggest converting to String the values before concatenating and after that, applying the datetime format.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your loop as follows:

```
For i = 2 To lRow
     Cells(i, 10) = Cells(i, 6) + Cells(i, 7)
     Cells(i, 11) = Cells(i, 8) + Cells(i, 9)
     Cells(i, 10).NumberFormat = "m/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss"
     Cells(i, 11).NumberFormat = "m/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss"
Next I
```

Of course, the formatting of columns J & K could be done in Excel, rather than in code, if that was easier for you.

The important thing is to just add the date and the time, not to try and create a string with the values joined together.  (The time `8:20:10` is just a number which is equal to 8/24 + 20/24/60 + 10/24/60/60, i.e. `0.347337962962963`, which is why the resultant string was being created as `1/23/2017 0.347337962962963` and, once it was a string then Excel is going to have a hard time treating it as anything else.)